# methods of aggregating data into a single collection

Tags: database, mongodb, aggregate

I am currently researching which Database to use for a software, and I have selected MongoDB however I cannot find any ways of aggregating data into a single collection. The two products and reviews collections can be aggregated together into a single collection, but what are the methods in aggregating data?

Comment: Please be more specific as to what you are trying to ask. Go through https://stackoverflow.com/help https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and try to formulate a better question. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/ has all the aggregations available with MongoDB explained. Please ask a specific question. if you have one